# When I use Eloquent methods like find() or sync() I get varius errors : 404 Not Found and some tims 500 internal server error

Tags: ajax, laravel, eloquent, modal-dialog

I use Bootstrap Modal for editing user roles. But without using form. just some Checkbox and a buttom for submitting operation. 
I use ajax to send data to coontroller. 
But in controller side when I want to use Eloquent methods, I get errros like 404 and 500. I really confused. I worked on it for more then 5 hours.

View :

```
<div class="modal" id="rolesEditModal"  role="dialog" >  <!--tabindex="-1"-->
                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                  <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                      <h5 class="modal-title">Edit Roles</h5>
                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                      </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="alert" id="imgMessage" style="display:none"></div>
                        <div class="modal-body  bg-gray">
                        <div class="editRolesElement">
                          <label for="modalTitle" id="userRolesLabel"><span> &nbsp;</span> User Roles </label>

                         <!-- checkbox -->
                         <div class="form-group form-check">
                                &nbsp;
                                <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="sysAdminCheckbox" id="checkbox1">
                                <label class="form-check-label" for="checkbox1" style="font-weight: bold;color: black">System Admin</label>
                         </div>
                         <div class="form-group form-check">
                                 <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="homePageAdminCheckbox"  id="checkbox2">
                                 <label class="form-check-label" for="checkbox2">HomaPage Admin</label>
                         </div>
                         <div class="form-group form-check">
                                 <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="aboutUsAdminCheckbox"  id="checkbox3">
                                 <label class="form-check-label" for="checkbox3">Aboutus Admin</label>
                          </div>
                        <div id="editmessage" style="display:none"></div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                          <button id="submitModal" type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal">save</button>
                          <!--<input type="submit" id="submitModal" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save">--><!--Save changes</button>-->
                        </div>
```

script :

```
<pre><code><script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready( function () {
$("#submitModal").click(function(){
        $('#editmessage').hide();
        var systemAdmin = 0;
        var homeAdmin = 0;
        var aboutUsAdmin = 0;
        var portfolioAdmin = 0;
        var featuresAdmin = 0;
        var contactusAdmin = 0;
        var commentAdmin = 0 ;
        if($('#checkbox1:checked').val()) 
            { systemAdmin = 1; } else { systemAdmin = 0; }
        if($('#checkbox2:checked').val())
            { homeAdmin = 1; } else { homeAdmin = 0; }
        if($('#checkbox3:checked').val())
            { aboutUsAdmin = 1; } else { aboutUsAdmin = 0; }
        if($('#checkbox4:checked').val())
            { portfolioAdmin = 1; } else { portfolioAdmin = 0; }
        if($('#checkbox5checked').val())
            { featuresAdmin = 1; } else { featuresAdmin = 0; }
        if($('#checkbox6:checked').val())
            { contactusAdmin = 1; } else { contactusAdmin = 0; }
        if($('#checkbox7:checked').val())
            { commentAdmin = 1; } else { commentAdmin = 0; }

        var A_url='';
        A_url = "{{ route('userManagement.editRoles') }}";
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
            });
        $.ajax({
                url : A_url,
                data : 
                {             
                    userId : $(this).data('userid'),
                    systemAdmin : systemAdmin,
                    homeAdmin : homeAdmin,
                    aboutUsAdmin : aboutUsAdmin,
                    portfolioAdmin : portfolioAdmin,
                    featuresAdmin : featuresAdmin,
                    contactusAdmin : contactusAdmin,
                    commentAdmin : commentAdmin 
                },
                type : 'post',
                fail: function(data){
                    var incerttxt = '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">Server error</div>';
                    $('#editmessage').html(incerttxt);
                    $('#editmessage').fadeIn();
                },
                success : function( data ) {
                    //updateUserList_afterEditRoles(data,selectedButton);
                    console.log(data);
                }
        });
        $('#rolesEditModal').modal('hide');
    });
```

the route :

```
Route::post('editRoles', 'UserManagementController@editRoles')->name('userManagement.editRoles');
```

controller :

```
    <pre><code>public function editRoles(Request $request)
{   
    $userId=$request["userId"];
    //$findedUser = User::find($userId)->roles()->orderBy('id')->get();
    $findedUser = User::findorfail($request['userId']);
    //$findedUser->roles()->detach();
    //$findedUser->roles()->attach($roleId);

    $assignedRoles = array();

    if ($request["systemAdmin"]==="1")
        { array_push($assignedRoles, 1); }
    if ($request["homeAdmin"]==="1")
        { array_push($assignedRoles, 2); }
    if ($request["aboutUsAdmin"]==="1")
        { array_push($assignedRoles, 3); }
    if ($request["portfolioAdmin"]==="1")
        { array_push($assignedRoles, 4); }
    if ($request["featuresAdmin"]==="1")
        { array_push($assignedRoles, 5); }
    if ($request["contactusAdmin"]==="1")
        { array_push($assignedRoles, 6); }
    if ($request["commentAdmin"]==="1")
        { array_push($assignedRoles, 7); }

$findedUser->roles()->sync([2,3,4]/*$assignedRoles*/);

return ($findedUser);
}
</code></pre>
```

Comment: Sometimes 500 when the code feels like it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I write the whole implementation without checking. Hope this will work well for you.
Did just small changes and improvements. So you can customize if you want..

**BLADE WITH SCRIPT**

```
<div class="modal" id="rolesEditModal" role="dialog" >
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Edit Roles</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="alert" id="imgMessage" style="display:none"></div>
            <div class="modal-body  bg-gray">
                <div class="editRolesElement">
                    <label for="modalTitle" id="userRolesLabel"><span> &nbsp;</span> User Roles </label>
                    @foreach($roles as $role)
                        <div class="form-group form-check">
                            <input data-id="{{ $role->id }}" type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="checkbox_{{ $role->id }}">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="checkbox_{{ $role->id }}">{{ $role->name }}</label>
                        </div>
                    @endforeach
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                <button id="submitModal" type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal">Save</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>

function getRoles() {
    let roles = {};
    $('#rolesEditModal .form-check-input').each(function(i) {
        roles [$(this).data('id')] = $(this).prop('checked');
    });
    return roles;
}

function submitRoles(roles) {
    $.ajax({
        data: {
            _token: "{{ csrf_token() }}",
            user_id: "{{ $user->id }}",
            roles: roles
        },
        url: "{{ route('userManagement.editRoles') }}",
        type: "POST"
    }).done(function (data) {
        console.log(data.message);
    }).fail(function (jqXHR, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        console.log("Server error!");
    });
}

function destructCheckboxes() {
    $('#rolesEditModal .form-check-input').prop('checked', false);
}

$("#submitModal").on('click', function() {
    let roles = getRoles();
    submitRoles(roles);
    destructCheckboxes();
    $('#rolesEditModal').modal('hide');
});

</script>
```

**ROUTE**

```
// here you just need to write one more route, which from action will return $roles collection and $user (or $users for your case with foreach in blade) object to the view
Route::post('editRoles', 'UserManagementController@editRoles')->name('userManagement.editRoles');
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
public function editRoles(Request $request)
{
    $user = User::findOrfail($request->get('user_id'));
    $roles = Role::whereIn('id', $request->get('roles'))->get();

    $user->roles()->delete();
    $user->roles()->saveMany($roles);

    return response()->json([
        'success' => true,
        'message' => "Roles successfully assigned to the user.",
    ], 200);
}
```

**NEW UPDATES**

In your controller you also have some method for getting your page, right?
I think in your blade you have one $user (for single user's page) or  $users (for showing multiple users). So I don't know what exactly in your blade, but you can use one of these methods for your specific case, or both them if you need:

```
public function singleUserPage($user_id)
{
    $user = User::findOrFail($user_id);
    $roles = Role::all();

    return view('user-management', [ // view for single user
        'user' => $user,
        'roles' => $roles,
    ]);
}

// for this you need to loop over on each user in the view, and it will have a same functionality
public function multipleUsersPage()
{
    $users = User::all();
    $roles = Role::all();

    return view('users-management', [ // view for multiple users
        'users' => $users,
        'roles' => $roles,
    ]);
}
```

You will have (or already have) appropriate routes for this methods like this:

```
Route::get('user/{user_id}', 'UserManagementController@singleUserPage')->name('user_page');
Route::get('users', 'UserManagementController@multipleUsersPage')->name('users_page');
```

So if you getting the $user as "undefined", you need to send that from controller to the page at first (as I in two methods on the top).

Comment: If you'll got the problem, ask here free

Comment: Thank you boolfalse. it was solved. But the main my error was sending undifine userId from the ajax method to the controller. Which in your code you correct this by : user_id: "{{ $user->id }}" . And you learn my coding so clear and professional. Thank you again
@boolfalse

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.. Hope it will help you. So I've updated the answer. Nothing changed, just added some new things for your comment-question